# How can MS Word 2013 still remember my last cursor point?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I really amazed how  can MS Word 2013 still remember my last cursor point ?

I deleted the document but I downloaded the document from my email inbox still it remembers where I left off.

[image: IMG:]

I know Vlc used to have this feature but forgot after system reboot but MS word remembers even after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature introduce with [Word 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-word-2013-3a9a927f-73ad-4ac5-910b-dfb12052d063) and also present in 2016/2019 versions

> Resume reading
>
> Reopen a document and keep reading right where you left off. Word remembers where you were—even when you reopen an online document from a different computer!

if you open the registry and goes to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Reading Locations\` for 2016 version (I presume for 2013 you should replace `16.0` with `15.0`), and expand it, you will seed a list of the document you worked on. Select one of the `Document #` keys. You should see on the right a key name `Position` contains information about the last position you were working on the files.

[image: IMG:]